# Android studio unzip firebase.aar failed

Tags: android

I'm trying to use Firebase for my project but when i included the gradle files and sync them,i get this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl1021Library'.
>   Unable to unzip 'E:\android-sdk-windows\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\firebase\firebase-analytics-impl\10.2.1\firebase-analytics-impl-10.2.1.aar' to 'C:\Users\lkhawlhing.android\build-cache\1d784cfc1bd0c2cb2e5ff993c4056bba42a118c8\output'

I Googled for a solution but the didn't find anything related to the error, can anyone help me with this problem.

Here's a Screenshot of the Log

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaGhm.jpg)

*Note :* Everything was working fine until i made a new user and once i log into the new user and install the android studio.I got the sdk files from a friend who is still currently using those without any problems.

Comment: Try with the new Android Studio 3.0 RC